# Unexpected background style appearing for check box in Chrome and IE11

Tags: html, checkbox, input

While selecting a native check box in chrome and IE11 the unexpected white background is apperaing (image attached).

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIymD.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="checkboxrow" id="checkboxrow_0"><input type="checkbox" name="file0" class="fileCheckbox"><div class="padding5p">Important_URLS.txt</div></div>
```

css:

```
.form_container .checkboxrow {
float: left;
width: 96%;
padding: 0px;
color: #666666;
height: 10;
font-size: 90%;
/* background: #FFFFFF; */
```

Comment: Show your code, if you want precise help

Comment: The code means, the `html` along with its `CSS`. Edit your question and add the "code" clearly

Comment: I added the html and css